# Время отклика php скрипта, при обращении ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, nginx, сокет

Разрабатываю *ajax* поиск по сайту. Использую *jquery*, *php*, *bitrix*. Имитирую скорость работы кода через **sleep()**. Запрос на сервер производится при вводе запроса, по событию **keyup()**. На событии ввода установлена задержка **ajax** запроса, и его **abort()** - в случае если пользователь продолжает ввод. Работает получше чем если отправлять запрос сразу после события **keyup()**. Однако этот велосипед всё равно не решает проблему.
[image: Network Browser Console]

Здесь: *синим* - отмечено время работы скрипта, если ввести один символ(либо уложиться в задержку(2сек) до выполнения ajax запроса); *зелёным* - время работы скрипта в случае ели пользователь продолжает ввод после начала **ajax** запроса(срабатывает **abort()**); *красным* - время работы скрипта после окончания ввода если был **xhr.abort()**.
Цифры говорят о том, что несмотря на abort на стороне клиента, сервер создаёт некую очередь для выполнения php-скрипта. Когда ввод не был ограничен задержками, скрипты работали вообще по очереди *2s,4s,6s*... Я конечно понимаю что проблема в бэкенде. И скорее всего дело даже не в коде, а в том что для правильной работы такого поиска нужно использовать технологию вроде **socket**. Хотя мне кажется что это избыточно в данном случае. Подскажите кто что знает пожалуйста, пока я ещё глупостей не наделал)))

Comment: В чем вопрос то? Что делает sleep()? Но подозреваю что правильный ответ на это – использование [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce)

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev sleep() использую потому что на сайте нет контента, как бы иммитирую запросы в базу данных

Comment: а за debounce спасибо, не знал о таком, заменю свой костыль на это

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev debounce плагин jquery отлично решил проблему. Большое спасибо!